# org.joda.DateTime returning wrong month

Tags: java, datetime

```
DateTimeFormatter d_t = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
String date = "02-Mar-2003 00:01";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date, d_t);
```

When I am running the code its returning 02-Jan-2003 12:01

Comment: what is it returning, what are you expecting? It is always important to include as much information about your error as possible

Answer (score 7):

Your date format string is wrong. Use `dd` instead of `DD` for the days.

According to [the documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), `DD` means "day of **year**", while you need `dd`, which means "day of **month**".

Change the first line to:

```
DateTimeFormatter d_t = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

Comment: no after changing to this pattern the date is not coming correct.

Comment: Now the output is 61-Mar-2003 12:01

Comment: How are you printing the result? Do you have the same problem there, using `DD` instead of `dd`? Fix it there too.